# How to build the AOSP to get jar file?

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-9.0-pie

I am new to the Android platform. I need to develop a system application so I need to access some `@SytemApi` annotated classed and some internal class in my Android system application.

After browsing for some time I found to write such application I need to have AOSP in my local drive, modify the source and then to compile to get the jar file to replace in /sdk/platforms/android-(xyz)/android.jar.

Could someone tell me how I can achieve this? I have downloaded the android 9 source code from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r41) and then tried to compile Android.mk with NDK build and couldn't achieve it.

Or Please advise me to the best way to achieve to write a system application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a Unix-based system (as building under Windows [is not supported](https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing)), go to the `bsp/android` directory and run the following commands:

**Prerequisite:** You must be using a OpenJDK-based JDK.

1. Set up the environment variables for your terminal session:

```
    $ . build/envsetup.sh
```

2. Choose the device architecture you wish to build against:

```
    $ lunch
```

3. Clean and build

```
    $ make clean
    $ make -j16
```

*NOTE:* The argument for `-j` should be double the number of cores your CPU has.

4. Go grab a coffee. This will take a **very** long time to build. As a reference, it takes over an hour on my workplace's beefed-up dedicated build servers, expect 2.5 hours or more on a moderate development laptop.

Once built, your AOSP outputs will be in the `out` directory, but you can change this by setting the `OUT_DIR` environment variable within your terminal session. Any system APKs should be located within the `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` folders within the `out` directory.

Comment: I am using windows..Do you have any work around way for windows?

Comment: Nope. Under ["Establishing a build environment"](https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing) it explicitly states that *"building under Windows is not currently supported"*. Worst comes to worst, install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (that documentation is out of date) on a virtual machine.

Comment: Okay :) Let me try.